Remove "Site.FullControl.All" from my Azure App registration, still allow us to access all sites
I have an Azure App registration, which has 2 permission for SharePoint, as follow:-

Sites.Selected
Sites.FullControl.All


Now I removed the "Sites.FullControl.All" >> but still using the ClientID & the Thumbprint related to this Azure App registration I can access all the sites and view all list and manage them
connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
Get-PnPList
So why removing the "Sites/FullControl.All" did not take effect? I did this 1 hour ago.
Thanks

Try add -ForceAuthentication to avoid using cached authentification.

@jleture yes worked,

@jleture if you can add you comment as an answer so i can accept it, and so it will be beneficial for others ... thanks

When changing permissions on an Entra ID registered application, you need to wait for a couple of minutes. Furthermore, it's better to close/reopen the PowerShell console or to force authentication with the -ForceAuthentication parameter:
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant -ForceAuthentication

